# A question on Kali-Puja

Tags: tantra, puja, kali

According to Tantra-Vachana, Kali-Puja should never be done by the priests. If someone gets it done by a priest, the Mother becomes angry and ruins that person:

> purohitam samAniya yadi pujAdi kArayaet/ tasya sarvArtha-hAnih syAt kruddhA bhavati kalikA// (Pranatoshini-Tantra, kanda 5, pari. 6)

Why then do we see priests doing kAli-puja in almost all cases? Is there any scriptural support of this practice?

Comment: @Rickross Any idea?...)

Comment: If the Purohits don't do then who will? Does that mean everyone willing to worship the Goddess must be initiated into it and start worshipping?

Comment: @Rickross yes, the order of this scripture is this.The Todala Tantra also implies this

Comment: But for temple worship who will do? It has to be the priests .. I think this injunction is meant for those who want to worship the Goddess in their house?

Comment: @Rickross no idea .,..

Comment: its for those who want to worship at their place. Not for public worship.